# Silverlight/WP7: .NET calls the wrong event

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7

I'm developping a Windows Phone 7 app with the Pivot template. This app has a menu toolbar (at the bottom of course).

When I click on the search button (`MenusButtonsApplication_Click` event to go to the "One" tab), a search page with a ListBox containing some elements is displayed.  When I click on one of these elements (`ListBoxFoobarSelectionChanged` event), I get redirected to another page to show me some details. I use this method.

To go back to the search page again, I must click twice on the search button (`MenusButtonsApplication_Click` event). Which is not normal.
After a debug, I found that the first click is related to the `ListBoxFoobarSelectionChanged` while calling the `MenusButtonsApplication_Click`.

This is the XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Test.Soft.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Phone.Controls.Samples;assembly=Phone.Controls.Samples"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
     mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <!--Ressources application-->

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontFamily>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneFontFamilyNormal"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontFamily>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontSize>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneFontSizeNormal"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.FontSize>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Foreground>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneForegroundBrush"/>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Foreground>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
       <controls:PivotControl x:Name="pvPrincipal" SelectedIndex="0" TitleTemplate="{StaticResource titleTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="480" FontSize="22" DefaultItemWidth="480" FontStretch="Normal"   Height="697" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,27,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible">

            <!-- Recherche de comptes -->
            <controls:PivotItem Name="pivotOne" Header="One" Loaded="PivotOne_Loaded">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="192*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="423*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                        <ListBox Name="lbSearch" Width="462"  Height="377"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="1"  
                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  SelectionChanged="ListBoxCompteSelectionChanged" >
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Padding="25,0,0,10" Text="{Binding FoobarCode}" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="- " />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FoobarDescription}" Padding="5,3,5,5" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </controls:PivotItem>


            <!-- Details -->
            <controls:PivotItem x:Name="pivotDetails" Header="Details" >
                <Grid  Name="grDetail"  Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="398*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="167*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ListBox>
                        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,12,20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   FontStyle="Normal" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Détail d'un compte</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= FoobarCode}" Name="tbCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Description}" Name="tbDescription" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />

                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" >
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </controls:PivotItem>

    </Grid>
    <!-- ApplicationBar-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar >
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnToPivotOne" IconUri="/Icons/appbar.plan.rest.png" Text="One" Click="MenusButtonsApplication_Click"></shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="menuToPivotOne" Text="To pivot One" Click="MenusButtonsApplication_Click"></shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
                </shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

This interface has:

- A pivot (pcPrincipal) containing two tabs (One and Details)
- An application bottom bar

For the two buggy functions, here they are:

```
private void ListBoxFoobarSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            grDetail.DataContext = lbSearch.SelectedItem;
            lblDescriptionType.Text = mainVM.RetourneDescriptionTypeEncours();
            pvPrincipalSelectedItem = pivotDetail;
        }



private void MenusButtonsApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ApplicationBarIconButton)
            {
                switch ((sender as ApplicationBarIconButton).Text)
                {
                    case "One":
                        // Affichage pivot plan
                        pvAccueil.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            pvPrincipal.SelectedItem = pivotOne;
                        });
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (sender is ApplicationBarMenuItem)
                {
                    switch ((sender as ApplicationBarMenuItem).Text)
                    {
                        case "To pivot One":
                            pvAccueil.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                pvPrincipal.SelectedItem = pivotOne;
                            });
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it a .NET bug? How can I resolve it? May be should I fire it manually?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example please.

Comment: Thanks for adding code but it isn't complete. It shows invalid XAML and the CS refers to objects which aren't in the XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the button you are using to navigtate back is in the listbox so the first time you "click" it you are actually just selecting the item in the list and the second "click" actually triggers the navigation.

If this is the case, the solution is to move the "Back/search" button outside of hte listbox.

Alternatively, have the navigation take place in the handler for the SelectionChanged event.

**Edit.**
What is `Phone.Controls.Samples.PivotControl`?
And why are you using this rather than the standard one?

Comment: The button is not in the ListBox: it's in the menu bar (at the bottom).

Comment: @Zakaria If you show the complete code to demonstrate this issue then I'd know this and not have to guess.

Comment: You were right Matt, the problem comes from the template that loads an inappropriate dll.